# Changing month position in daterangepicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, css, daterangepicker

I am using daterangepicker plugin and is working perfectly fine. But when the calendar popup opens, it shows the current month in left and next month in right. How to set the current month to right and last month to left? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `dateLimit` option. That may help in solving your problem